# awk parameter substitution fails

Tags: command-line, bash, awk

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 Mate Desktop environment.

I encounter a strange failure when I attempt to pass the `date` string to regex query in the following line :

```
  date="2020-12-11"

  cat /var/log/dpkg.log | awk  ' / installed / && /$date/ {print $5}'
```

I tried different combinations  as suggested in the forums:

```
  cat /var/log/dpkg.log | awk  ' / installed / && /${date}/ {print $5}'

  cat /var/log/dpkg.log | awk  ' / installed / && "/$date/" {print $5}'
```

But they won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass variables in either using the `-v` command line option:

```
date="2020-12-11"

cat /var/log/dpkg.log | awk  -v date="$date" ' / installed / && $0 ~ date {print $5}'
```

or via the `ENVIRON` array in the case of environment variables

```
export date="2020-12-11"

cat /var/log/dpkg.log | awk  -v date="$date" ' / installed / && $0 ~ ENVIRON["date"] {print $5}'
```

See for example [Pass shell variable as a /pattern/ to awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120788/pass-shell-variable-as-a-pattern-to-awk)

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works but though it's mentioned in documents https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-Shell-Variables.html, why it doesn't work in my case?

Comment: @kenn the example in the link uses double quotes - you used single quotes, which prevent the shell from expanding the variable.

Comment: I get it now. Actually I thought of it and tried different combinations but I failed in my attempts.

Comment: Is there any way to arrange my line to work the way I expected?

Comment: @kenn yes you could have written `awk "/ installed / && /$date/ {print \$5}"` for example (note the backslash escaping of `$5` to prevent **it** from being prematurely expanded by the shell). But it's not recommended for the reasons discussed in the link you provided (*"[it] can potentially be messy. It requires a good understanding of the shell’s quoting rules, and it’s often difficult to correctly match up the quotes when reading the program."*)

Comment: How come this line expands correctly in single quotes but it fails in the result? `echo "cat /var/log/dpkg.log | awk  ' / installed / && "/$date/" {print $5}'"` expands to `cat /var/log/dpkg.log | awk  ' / installed / && /2020-12-11/ {print }'`

Comment: @kenn there are 2 problems with that: (1) inside double quotes, the single quotes are passed to awk literally - resulting in invalid awk syntax. (2) `$5` is expanded by the shell, and is treated as an empty positional parameter. That's why it *"requires a good understanding of the shell’s quoting rules"*.

Comment: It is the underlying shell, in this case, `bash` that interprets *quotations*. Bash reads quotes from left to right (in your case, it means `/$date/` is unquoted). In single-quote, all character loses there meaning, even backslash. In doublequote, single-quotes bare no meaning. Double-quotes will also honor escape, expand variables and subcommands, etc. Next, the evaluated string will be processed by awk even further.